# Goldfish dropped on floor, then it started swimming upside down

Tags: aquarium, injury, goldfish

I am feeding pair of goldfish in bowl. I do change the water everyday morning, because I am filling the bowl with tap water.

While cleaning the bowl today morning, it jumped out and dropped on floor from 4 feet (120 cm) height. Then immediately I put her back in bowl, then it started swimming upside-down. What should I do to make my gold fish normal?

The following picture I took when it was swimming normally.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that they've gotten brain damage and there is probably not much you can do about that, you would need to see an aquatic vet for a proper assessment. If you want to improve the quality of their life I suggest buying an aquarium. It is **extremely harmful** to keep goldfish in bowls, the only fish that can be kept in bowls are bettas. Goldfish need proper aquariums to live out their full lives.

Comment: Even for Bettas, it is far from optimal... This bowl can handle tiny shrimp at best!

Comment: hey @malik, thanks for answer , finally i found the exact reason. Her right pectoral fin has damaged. My fish can able to swim but she unable to balance, so the total body is turning upside down. is damaged can grow back. I am changing water once in two days and dechlorin everytime

Comment: That's good it's not brain damage, but you still need to change to an aquarium or else your goldfish will have a very short life.

Comment: okay, i'll chnage it to fish tank from bowl, any suggestions to make my fish fin grow faster?

Comment: Creating a healthy environment will help, but that's about all that you can do I'm afraid. Here is some more information: http://animals.mom.me/fishs-tail-fin-regrow-5000.html 
But make sure that you keep an eye on it and check there are no infections. If you see signs of an infecion, you might have to start giving antibiotics. Also, have a look at this article regarding keeping goldfish in a fishtank: https://puregoldfish.com/what-size-tank-do-goldfish-need/ . In my opinion, a bowl like that is not suitable to keep any living pets in. A Betta also needs more space, a heather, a filter,...